# How to confirm that LDAP SSL patches are working

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ldap

We have applied the LDAP SSL Security Elevation patches on our domain controller, and have set the `LdapEnforceChannelBinding` entry to 2 (to force a hard fail for insecure connections), but all of my attempts have been successful, leading me to believe that either the patch isn't properly applied, or the registry setting hasn't been made to the right place.

Can someone provide a script or program that we can point to our LDAP server that can definitively say whether or not this mitigation is in place and working?

Note: I posted this to Stack Overflow after seeing a similar post there about LDAP, but then I thought about it for a bit and determined that Server Fault would be a better place for this question.

Comment: `but all of my attempts have been successful, leading me to believe that either the patch isn't properly applied, or the registry setting hasn't been made to the right place.` Why is that? Are you able to perform a simple bind using basic authentication on tcp/389?

Comment: We have two places where it needs to work for our customers, one within a Delphi application that uses a Jedi code library that looks like it's connecting on tcp/389, and a second on a web page that uses a library from IP*Works that I *think* is also connecting on tcp/389.  Both of these work, with the mitigations in place.  However, we have tools we've used in the past to validate our LDAP connections (LDAP Search from SecurityXploded.com and LDAP Browser from Softerra) but I can't get either of them to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot connect using LDAP Browser that is a good sign.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-march-update/ba-p/921536

If a basic auth on tcp/389 is attempted and is rejected, an event Id 2888 event will be recorded in the Directory Services event log every 24 hours to summarize. So your LDAP Browser failed attempts should be logged there.

Probably a good idea to get more information about the apps though.  I would not assume it is using basic auth.

Comment: So, I searched the Domain Server's Event Viewer for event 2888, but found nothing.  
I reduced the `LdapEnforceChannelBinding` to 0 and tried connecting again with the LDAP Browser from Softerra and still can't connect (Error 91).  

I don't have a lot of experience with LDAP/AD, but I'll start with the LDAP Browser, getting it to connect, and will continue troubleshooting *after* I have succeeded, because LDAP Browser should give me the information I need to be certain that things are or aren't working correctly.

Comment: I upgraded to LDAP Browser 4.5 (I was using 2.5), and installed it on our web server (not the Domain Server), and was able to connect successfully, but could not from my local workstation.  While I would like to be able to do all testing from the workstation, the fact that I can connect successfully from the web server means I can continue my testing.  Thank you for the help, and I'll reply back with my progress.

Comment: OK, I changed the `LdapEnforceChannelBinding` entry to 2 again, and the LDAP Browser on my web server could still connect, using port 389, and Simple credentials.  That has to mean that the mitigation isn't correctly installed on the LDAP server, yes?

Comment: @Dan: seems that way